# Modified button resets back on scroll ListView

Tags: android, listview

I'm creating a listview by using a Json data. I'm populating some Images, text fields and a button. When user clicks on the button buttons caption is changes.

Problem is that if button is modified and user scrolled the listview button resets to first status. Please check this video it is better to explain : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=57ZraP7ED2E&feature=youtu.be

Adapter

```
public class FilmRequestAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<FilmRequest>{
    Context context;
    List<FilmRequest> data;

    public FilmRequestAdapter(Context context, int resource, List<FilmRequest> objects) {
        super(context, resource, objects);
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub

        this.context=context;
        this.data=objects;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View row=convertView;

        if (row==null) {
            LayoutInflater inflater=((Activity)context).getLayoutInflater();
            row=inflater.inflate(R.layout.film_request_list,null);
        }

        ((TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.FilmRequestFilmTitle)).setText(((FilmRequest)data.get(position)).title);
        ((TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.FilmRequestRating)).setText("Imdb Puanı : "+((FilmRequest)data.get(position)).rating);
        ((TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.FilmRequestOrder)).setText("Sıra : "+((FilmRequest)data.get(position)).order);
        ((TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.FilmRequestVoteCount)).setText("Oya adeti : "+((FilmRequest)data.get(position)).voteCount);

        Button button=(Button)row.findViewById(R.id.FilmRequestActionButton);
        String status=((FilmRequest)data.get(position)).status;
        boolean requested=((FilmRequest)data.get(position)).requested;
        boolean voted=((FilmRequest)data.get(position)).voted;
        if (status.equalsIgnoreCase("A") || status.equalsIgnoreCase("")) {

            if (requested) {
                if (voted) {
                    button.setText("Oylanmış");
                    button.setEnabled(false);
                }else {
                    button.setText("+ Oyla");
                    button.setEnabled(true);
                    button.setTag(R.string.film_request_action, "VOTEABLE");
                    button.setTag(R.string.film_request_id,((FilmRequest)data.get(position)).id);
                }
            } else {
                button.setText("Filmi İste");
                button.setEnabled(true);
                button.setTag(R.string.film_request_action, "REQUESTABLE");
                button.setTag(R.string.film_request_id,((FilmRequest)data.get(position)).imdbId);               
            }

        } else {
            button.setText("Eklenmiş");
            button.setEnabled(false);
        }

        button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                FilmRequestActivity.ButtonClickFunction(context,(Button)v);
            }
        });

        ((ImageView)row.findViewById(R.id.FilmRequestPoster)).setImageBitmap(((FilmRequest)data.get(position)).bm);

        return row;

    }

}
```

Async Class

```
public class FilmRequestAsync extends AsyncTask<String, Void, List<FilmRequest>>{

    Context context;
    ListView listView;
    private ProgressDialog progressDialog;

    public FilmRequestAsync (Context context) {
        this.context=context;
        this.listView=(ListView) ((Activity)context).findViewById(R.id.FilmRequestList);
    }

    protected void onPreExecute() {
        this.progressDialog = ProgressDialog.show(context, "Lütfen Bekleyin...", "Fimler Yükleniyor...",true);
    }   

    @Override
    protected List<FilmRequest> doInBackground(String... params) {
        Log.d("debug","FilmRequestAsync param[0]"+params[0]);
        List<FilmRequest> filmRequests=null;
        String jsonString;

        try {
            jsonString=GeneralFunctions.getUrl(params[0]);
            if (jsonString!=null) {

                 filmRequests=this.getFilmRequestListFromJsonString(jsonString);

            }
        }catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return filmRequests;        


    }

    private List<FilmRequest> getFilmRequestListFromJsonString(String jsonString){
        List<FilmRequest> filmRequests=new ArrayList<FilmRequest>();
        try {
            Log.d("debug","Json Verisi oluşturuluyor.");
            JSONArray json=new JSONArray(jsonString);
            Log.d("debug","Json Verisi Oluşturuldu");

            int i;
            for (i=0;i<json.length();i++) {
                JSONObject tmpJson=(JSONObject)json.get(i);
                filmRequests.add(
                    new FilmRequest(
                            tmpJson.getString("id"),
                            tmpJson.getString("imdb_id"),
                            tmpJson.getString("poster"),
                            tmpJson.getString("title"),
                            tmpJson.getString("rating"),
                            tmpJson.getString("order"),
                            tmpJson.getString("status"),
                            tmpJson.getString("vote_count"),
                            tmpJson.getBoolean("requested"),
                            tmpJson.getBoolean("voted")
                            )
                );
                tmpJson=null;
            }

        } catch (JSONException e) {
            Log.d("debug","Json Verisi HATASI:");

            filmRequests=null;
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return filmRequests;        
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(List<FilmRequest> result) {
            this.progressDialog.dismiss();
            if (result==null) return;

            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            super.onPostExecute(result);
            Log.d("debug", "FilmRequestAsync onPostExecute Başı");

            FilmRequestAdapter filmRequestAdapter=new FilmRequestAdapter(context, R.layout.film_request_list, result);
            Log.d("debug","FilmRequestAsync:Adapter set ediliyor.");
            listView.setAdapter(filmRequestAdapter);
            Log.d("debug", "onPostExecute Sonu");
        }
}
```

List Xml File

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/film_container"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="2dp"
    android:background="@drawable/film_list_style"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:padding="3dp" >

    <!--  ListRow Left sied Thumbnail image -->

    <!-- Title Of Song-->

    <!-- Artist Name -->

    <!-- Rightend Duration -->

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/FilmRequestPoster"
        android:layout_width="83dp"
        android:layout_height="106dp" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/FilmRequestActionButton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:text="+ Oyla" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/FilmRequestRating"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/FilmRequestFilmTitle"
        android:layout_below="@+id/FilmRequestFilmTitle"
        android:text="Rating" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/FilmRequestVoteCount"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/FilmRequestOrder"
        android:layout_below="@+id/FilmRequestOrder"
        android:text="VoteCount" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/FilmRequestFilmTitle"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/FilmRequestActionButton"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/FilmRequestPoster"
        android:text="Rihanna Love the way lie"
        android:textColor="#040404"
        android:textSize="15dip"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:typeface="sans" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/FilmRequestOrder"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/FilmRequestRating"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/FilmRequestPoster"
        android:text="Order" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Click Functions

```
    public static void ButtonClickFunction(Context context, Button button){
        //Burası Ne işlem yapabileceğimizi gösteriyor.
        //REQUESTABLE veya VOTABLE değerleri alabilir.
        String action=(String)button.getTag(R.string.film_request_action);
        String id=(String)button.getTag(R.string.film_request_id);

        Log.d("debug", "String action="+action);

        if (action.equalsIgnoreCase("VOTEABLE")) {
            VoteFilm(context, button,id);
        } else if (action.equalsIgnoreCase("REQUESTABLE")) {
            RequestFilm(context, button, id);
        }
    }   

    public static void VoteFilm(Context context, final Button button, final String id){
        final String callUrl=context.getString(R.string.api_url)+"?request=vote_film&user_id=1&id="+id;
        Log.d("debug", "FilmRequestActivity->VoteFilm->callUrl:"+callUrl);
        new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    GeneralFunctions.getUrl(callUrl);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                button.post(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        button.setText("Oylanmış");
                        button.setEnabled(false);
                    }
                });
            }
        }).start();
        Toast.makeText(context, "Film Oylandı", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show(); 
    }

    public static void RequestFilm(Context context, final Button button,final String id){
        final String callUrl=context.getString(R.string.api_url)+"?request=request_film&user_id=1&id="+id;
        Log.d("debug", "FilmRequestActivity->RequestFilm->callUrl:"+callUrl);

        new Thread(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                String jsonString;
                final JSONObject jsonObject;
                try {
                    jsonString = GeneralFunctions.getUrl(callUrl);
                    jsonObject=GeneralFunctions.StringToJSONObject(jsonString);
                    if (jsonObject!=null) {
                        button.post(new Runnable() {
                            @Override
                            public void run() {

                                try {
                                    Log.d("debug","Inside Thread");
                                    JSONObject data=(JSONObject) jsonObject.get("data");
                                    String new_id=data.getString("id");
                                    button.setTag(R.string.film_request_action,"VOTEABLE");
                                    button.setTag(R.string.film_request_id,new_id);
                                    button.setText("+Oyla");
                                    button.setEnabled(true);

                                } catch (JSONException e) {
                                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                                    e.printStackTrace();
                                }

                            }
                        });

                    }                   
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }).start();

    }
}
```

Comment: What is this doing? : `FilmRequestActivity.ButtonClickFunction(context,(Button)v);` Can you post code for this method?

Comment: Vikram I have updated it.

Comment: the better way is in ButtonClickFunction change the data and call notifyDataSetChanged http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/BaseAdapter.html#notifyDataSetChanged()

Comment: Sudar But I that, think I need to reload data to call notifyDataSetChanged. But I'm loading the data from web site. It takes 2-3 seconds. I can't make wait user for each button click.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that you never modify the content of your adapter when you call `ButtonClickFunction`. This way when you scroll, the hold state is met and the old string is set to your button. I suggest you to think better about your design. As quick fix, you can set another tag to your Button, adding the FilmRequest object at position, for instance:

```
    final FilmRequest filmRequest = (FilmRequest)data.get(position);
    String status = filmRequest.status;
    boolean requested = filmRequest.requested;
    boolean voted = filmRequest.voted;
```

then, inside the `ButtonClickFunction`, retrieve this tag and change its `status` accordingly

Answer (score 0):

You aren't using the ViewHolder pattern correctly. You have to create a ViewHolder and use the setTag and getTag to store the state of your item:

```
    if (convertView == null) {
        convertView.setTag(holder);
    } else {
        holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }
```

Comment: I think my problem is not about getTag and setTag. Buttons are populating automaticly. So I can't manage each button with settag.

Comment: Akram, I think he is not using the pattern at all.

Answer (score 0):

I was same issue but I solve by this code

```
public class CustomizeListView extends ListActivity {

    LayoutInflater inflater;
    static int index = 0;

    // AutoCompleteTextView autoCompleteTextView;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_order);
        inflater = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        ArrayAdapter<String> dataAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, arrayList_Category);
        dataAdapter
                .setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);

        final CustomAdapter adapter = new CustomAdapter(this,
                R.layout.activity_orderitem, arrayListItems);
        setListAdapter(adapter);
    }

    private class CustomAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<HashMap<String, Object>>
            implements OnItemSelectedListener {
        boolean[] checkBoxState;
        ViewHolder viewHolder;

        public CustomAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId,
                ArrayList<HashMap<String, Object>> arrayListItems) {
            // let android do the initializing :)
            super(context, textViewResourceId, arrayListItems);
            checkBoxState = new boolean[arrayListItems.size()];
        }

        // class for caching the views in a row
        private class ViewHolder {
            CheckBox checkBox;
        }

        @Override
        public View getView(final int position, View convertView,
                ViewGroup parent) {
            Log.d("getView", "getView");
            if (convertView == null) {
                convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_orderitem,
                        null);
                viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
                // cache the views
                convertView.setTag(viewHolder);
            } else
                viewHolder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();

            viewHolder.checkBox.setChecked(checkBoxState[position]);

            viewHolder.checkBox.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    if (((CheckBox) v).isChecked()) {
                        checkBoxState[position] = true;
                    } else {
                        checkBoxState[position] = false;
                    }
                }
            });

            return convertView;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion you're using the views to store its state, so when the view is recycled in the scroll, the original element loses the state, even the state could be assigned to other elements that obtains the recycled view.
Try to store the state of an element not in the view but in an different structure in the adapter.